# How can I install Ubuntu Studio on Alienware 17

Tags: system-installation, uefi, ubuntu-studio, alienware

I am aware that there are "versions" of this question out on the web, but none of them work for me. I absolutely do not want to install Ubuntu Studio in a VMware (or other) virtual machine on top of Windows. I want to do the opposite. I have VMWare 12 Pro, as well as VMware converter, with the intention of taking my windows image and putting it inside Ubuntu Studio. Also, I do NOT want to dual boot. I want no native Windows what-so-ever!

Regarding my installation problems... I HAVE tried turning off UEFI Boot, changing to Legacy with secuire mode off. I then choose to boot from the CD (F12 at startup). I get as far as the initial splash screen for Ubuntu Studio, then it seems to freeze. (For the record, the exact same issue occurs for me with Kubuntu).

I will continue searching for solutions on my own, but hope someone here can help me. Just for the sake of mentioning it, I am able to install and run Kali Linux, but as a musician, I really want and need Studio. I mention simply to indicate that my laptop can handle some distros, in case this is of any use.

Please let me know if I need to provide additional information, such as the output of any hardware identifying commands, etc.

Thank you in advance for anything you can do for me. I really hope there is a solution that puts Ubuntu Studio on THIS laptop! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this will answer your question , but i had the same issue installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my alienware m17x , couldn't find a fit solution for it, ive fixed it by removing dell raid and made my hd with non-raid standard.

doing so after bios menu , `ctrl+i` , and i deleted dell raid partition then installed Ubuntu on it.

*notice :* what i did is deleting all the hd. before doing so backup your alienware drivers and applications in a flash drive, because all alienware drives and applications are based on java/jar, so there is a way to combine them into Ubuntu.

`cross-complied` alienware `alienfx-lite`

1. read first:
   (http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/alienfx-lite-linux-windows-alienfx-tool.458528/)
2. getting alienware fx:

   install git:

   `sudo apt-get install git`

   clone alienware fx:

   `sudo git clone https://github.com/r0ttten/AlienFxLite`

Comment: please let me know if everything went well , i have the interest to install Ubuntu studio on my alienware too